# gpload throws exception with "ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe5b82e"

Tags: utf-8, greenplum

When I use gpload to dump some data into greenplum, it failed due to one error: "ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe5b82e".

I did some search for it. My greenplum is 5.18.0, and "show client_encoding" showes "UTF8", and while I check the data file with "file" command, it also showes:text/plain; charset=utf-8. This is what confused me: data file is utf8, and the client is also utf8, why it throws such error? I failed to find out some \x0 or \u0000 char in this string which was the key issue for same question in some post.

I found one link seems about this problem: https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-6191
Is it really a bug about this greenplum version?

And one more thing about data file, it's text file with '|' as delimitor, and its content is as following:

```
|Hibernate operation: could not insert: [net.xiaofei.apps.wbps.channel.entity.IntSoapContent]; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into int_soap_content (case_id, casetype, channel, content, create_time, handle_flag, handle_time, srccaseid, subcasetype) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1366]; Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA1\x8D\xB2\xE5\xB8...' for column 'content' at row 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA1\x8D\xB2\xE5\xB8...' for column 'content' at row 1|20190818
```

Any help is appreciated!

I don't want to start a new thread for this post, so I show the steps here:

1. create table in greenplum db: `

> CREATE TABLE test (id bigint,result text) WITH(appendonly=true,
>   compresstype=quicklz, orientation=column) DISTRIBUTED BY (id);

`

2. write following content into data file: `

> 5661083|Hibernate operation: could not insert:
>   [net.xiaofei.apps.wbps.channel.entity.IntSoapContent]; uncategorized
>   SQLException for SQL [insert into int_soap_content (case_id, casetype,
>   channel, content, create_time, handle_flag, handle_time, srccaseid,
>   subcasetype) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [HY000];
>   error code [1366]; Incorrect string value:
>   '\xF0\xA1\x8D\xB2\xE5\xB8...' for column 'content' at row 1; nested
>   exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value:
>   '\xF0\xA1\x8D\xB2\xE5\xB8...' for column 'content' at row 1

`

3. write yaml file as following:

> ```
> VERSION: 1.0.0.1
> DATABASE: test
> USER: userXXX
> PASSWORD: passYYY
> HOST: ip1.ip2.ip3.ip4
> PORT: 3421
> GPLOAD:
>     INPUT:
>         - SOURCE:
>             LOCAL_HOSTNAME:
>                 - ip1.ip2.ip3.ip4
>             PORT: 6006
>             FILE:
>                 - /tmp/gpdb_test/test/*
>         - COLUMNS:
>                - id:  integer
>                - result:  text
>         - FORMAT: text
>         - DELIMITER: '|'
>         - ESCAPE: OFF
>         - NULL_AS: '\N'
>         - ERROR_LIMIT: 0
>     OUTPUT:
>         - TABLE: test
>         - MODE: INSERT
>     PRELOAD:
>         - TRUNCATE: true
>     SQL:
>         - BEFORE: "INSERT INTO gpload_audit VALUES(nextval('gpload_audit_seq'), 'start', 'insert', 'test', current_timestamp)"
>         - AFTER: "INSERT INTO gpload_audit VALUES(nextval('gpload_audit_seq'), 'end', 'insert', 'test', current_timestamp)"
> ```

4. run "gpload -f test.yaml', then it will throw error:

> ```
> 2019-08-20 10:27:14|INFO|gpload session started 2019-08-20 10:27:14
> 2019-08-20 10:27:14|INFO|setting schema 'public' for table 'test'
> 2019-08-20 10:27:19|INFO|started gpfdist -p 6006 -P 6007 -f "/home/work/gpdb_test/test/*" -t 30
> 2019-08-20 10:27:20|ERROR|ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe5b82e  (seg9 slice1 10.136.173.8:33001 pid=339845)
> DETAIL:  External table ext_gpload_05bdc0fe_c2f2_11e9_bb6b_246e9677a1f0, line 1 of  gpfdist://10.136.157.44:6006//home/work/gpdb_test/test/*:  "5661083|Hibernate operation: could not insert:  [net.xiaofei.apps.wbps.channel.entity.IntSoapContent]..."       encountered while running INSERT INTO public."test" ("id","result") SELECT "id","result" FROM ext_gpload_05bdc0fe_c2f2_11e9_bb6b_246e9677a1f0
>
> 2019-08-20 10:27:20|INFO|rows Inserted          = 0
> 2019-08-20 10:27:20|INFO|rows Updated           = 0
> 2019-08-20 10:27:20|INFO|data formatting errors = 0
> 2019-08-20 10:27:20|INFO|gpload failed
> ```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] before posting here, your question's off-topic without that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, sorry for this unprofessional post. I added step to reproduce this problem at the end of this post. May you please have a look at it ? Thx.

Comment: Firstly, you can always edit your question to clarify it, that's perfectly fine. Now, make sure you can follow your instructions in order to reproduce the issue without any additional info. With your steps, I couldn't execute "write following content into data file" apart from being puzzeled by the fact that it contains an error message.

Comment: After you put the content with | as delimitor into a text file, you can dump it into greenplum db without above error?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure what encoding your source files are.
Second, if you have access to the file, run "locale;grep -axv file.txt". If it returns something, it means your file contains invalid byte sequence or your file is corrupted.
Third, you can use iconv to fix/skip the invalid sequence bytes or go back to your source to get the right encoding.

Comment: grep -axv my file keeps running without any result. I tried it on different files while with same result. Can you run same command on your machine?